# how to add jsf com.sun.faces in websphere 9

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, websphere

I want to start my app using com.sun.faces jsf and primefaces dependency in websphere 9.

The part of pox.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.13</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.13</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I added jsf-impl-2.2.8-30.jar and jsf-api-2.2.8-30.jar to shared libs in WebSphere (Enterprise Applications > app_name > Shared library references, for application and for module) and got exception in log:

```
    Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=OPOLSKYNode01,version=9.0.0.9,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=OPOLSKYNode01Cell,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
    Exception 0 :
    javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    ....
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.faces.util.cdi11.CDIUtil: Provider com.sun.faces.util.cdi11.CDIUtilImpl not a subtype
...
```

Later I found that there was a warning written in websphere (Enterprise Applications > app_name > JSP and JSF options):
Version 9.0 and later nodes use the MyFaces JSF implementation, even if SunRI is selected in a mixed-cell environment. For more configuration information, read about JavaServer Faces in the product documentation.

And I tried to add a shared libraries with mojarra-jsf-impl-2.0.0-b04.jar and mojarra-jsf-api-2.0.0-b04.jar

but got:

```
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@bce1c60f[war:isclite/isclite.war]
   Local ClassPath: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\systemApps\isclite.ear\isclite.war\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\systemApps\isclite.ear\isclite.war\WEB-INF\lib\abdera.client.0.2.2-incubating.jar;C:\Program
...
00000093 annotations   W ScannerContextImpl getInputDataForClass   Class loader [ 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@2d433080[app:isclite]
   Local ClassPath: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\systemApps\isclite.ear\lib\batik-all.jar;C:\Program 
...
```

Help me please! 
Is it possible to start app with jsf dependency in websphere ?

Comment: Are you using either PARENT_LAST class loading or setting the "isolated class loader" setting on the shared library? One or the other would be necessary to get your application-provided classes picked up in preference to those provided by the server.

Comment: @Jarid Thank you. I use the PARENT_LAST option but only in Enterprise Applications > app_name> Manage Modules > app_name and the "isolated class loader" setting on the shared library and application started.

Comment: @Vadim, when you said "..and application started" did you mean the app starts correctly with those settings?  Mojarra 2.2.8 should work correctly on WAS 9.

Comment: @wtlucy Yes, the app works correctly with jsf-api-2.2.8-30.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.8-30.jar in shared libraries.